# Query error MySQL with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I have a problem in executing a query with MySQL and PHP. 
I connect to the database with PDO and when I run the query it returns the following errors:

```
errorCode = 42000 
errorInfo = array ([0] => 00000 [1] => [2] =>)
```

After the modifications suggested, the code I use is this

```
require "connPDO.php";
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$PDO->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$stmt = $PDO->prepare("INSERT INTO 'titacc' ('file', 'RGS', 'RGP', 'RGD', 'RGDG',          'RGOG', 'DenOrg', 'CodFiscOrg', 'TipoOrg', 'IntrTipoTass', 'IntrIncid', 'DenLocale', 'CodLocale', 'DataEv', 'OraEv',
'TipoGen', 'IncidGen', 'OrdPostoCodOrd', 'OrdPostoCapienza', 'TitoloEv', 'ProduttoreCinema', 'Autore', 'Esecutore', 'Nazionalita', 'Distributore', 'TATipoTit', 'TAQta',
'TACorrLordo', 'TAPrevendita', 'TAIVACorr', 'TAIVAPrev', 'TAImpPrest') VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?");

$stmt->execute(array(
$file,
$RGS,
$RGP,
$RGD,
$RGDG,
$RGOG,
$DenOrg,
$CodFiscOrg,
$TipoOrg,
$IntrTipoTass,
$IntrIncid,
$DenLocale,
$CodLocale,
$DataEv,
$OraEv,
$TipoGen,
$IncidGen,
$OrdPostoCodOrd,
$OrdPostoCapienza,
$TitoloEv,
$ProduttoreCinema,
$Autore,
$Esecutore,
$Nazionalita,
$Distributore,
$TATipoTit,
$TAQta,
$TACorrLordo,
$TAPrevendita,
$TAIVACorr,
$TAIVAPrev,
$TAImpPrest
));
if (! $stmt->exe1cute() )
{
echo "<b>Errore nella query!</b>"; echo"<br/>";
print_r($stmt->errorCode()); echo"<br/>";
print_r($stmt->errorInfo()); echo"<br/>";
print_r($PDO->errorInfo()); echo"<br/>";
die();
} else {
echo "<b>Inserimento avvenuto con successo</b>";
}
$PDO = null;
```

I read other posts and attempted to fix this, but the error remains.
If the query is executed from the console, I have no error.

Comment: I don't know where your problem is yet, but when using an extension like PDO you should also make use of prepared statements ([bindParam()](http://php.net/manual/de/pdostatement.bindparam.php) or [bindValue()](http://www.php.net/manual/de/pdostatement.bindvalue.php), alternatively you can replace them directly in the `execute()`-function). This makes your code significantly easier to understand and to maintain, and is safe against SQL injections.

Comment: Do `echo $query` and see what the output is, you have an error in your syntax. Also, why would you use pdo like that?

Comment: @Kasipovic: I tried it with echo and do not receive any error...

Comment: @Padarom:Thanks for the info. I have read and applied, but the error is always the same

Answer (score 3):

Use prepared statements.

```
$st = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO `table`(`col1`, `col2`) VALUES (:col1value, :col2value)");
```

Then on execute give argument

```
$st->execute(array(
    'col1value'=>$value1,
    'col2value'=>$value2
));
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php#109030

Comment: I modified as suggested, but the error is always the same

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$PDO->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$stmt = $PDO->prepare("INSERT INTO tbl VALUES (?, ?, ... ?");
$stmt->execute(array(
    $col1,
    $col2,
    ...
    $col31
));
```

and post here the *real* query with real code you run.

Comment: after making the suggested changes, I get the following error: Fatal Error: Uncaught Exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the ryght syntax to use near "at line 6' in file.php Stack trace: #0 file.php(126):PDOStatement->execute(Array)#1 {main} thrown in file.php on line 126

Comment: at line 126 I have the following code: ));

Comment: you have to show line 6 of your **query**

Comment: I modified the request with the actual query

Comment: that's what you had to do in the first place. you are using wrong quotes. remove quotes from table and field names

Comment: I removed the quotes around the table name and field names, but the error remains ...

Comment: I applied the quotes on tables and fields by following the suggestions given on this post [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10556941/php-pdo-syntax-error-or-access-violation-1064-on-insert)

Comment: there is no line 6 in the query yuo posted here. you have to post EXACT CODE YOU RUN and get error with

Comment: solved ... there was a syntax error .. I inserted exe1cute instead of execute the line: if (! $ stmt-> exe1cute ()). 
Thank you all for your suggestions and availability.