# Exception on execute() with prepared statements

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, transactions, prepared-statement

This really looks like simple task but still, kicking my head against the wall last few hours and searching the web for any clue to solve this didn't help as well.

**Error:**

In short I'm getting exception on first [execute()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) call inside [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loop.

```
Error while execute data (User1, Group1)

exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access
violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'group)
VALUES ('User1', 'Group1')' at line 2' in C:\wamp\www\dbo-test-transactions.php:32
Stack trace: #0 C:\wamp\www\dbo-test-transactions.php(32):
PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 {main}
```

**What I use?**

WAMP 2.4 on Windows; Database host, username and password have default values ("localhost", "root" and ""). I have created database `test` (colation: **utf8_general_ci**) with table `users` (two columns `user_name` and `group`). Both columns are **VARCHAR(50)** and `user_name` column has **PRIMARY KEY**. Database engine is **InnoDB**.

[image]

**What have I tried?**

I've already tried to execute queries directly using [query()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php) and "real" mysql query, with no transactions, and it works well. But when I try to use prepared statements it keeps failing. Also, I've tried using different approach with [bindParam()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) or [bindValue()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php) but final result is always the same - **it throws exception**.

Have already checked a lot of resources, mostly here on StackOverflow, [PHP.net](http://php.net/) and [MySQL.com](http://www.mysql.com/), read all, letter by letter, checked all examples, comments, etc.

**Relevant code**

My database connection has been established using this piece of code.

```
try {
  $pdo = @new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;charset=utf8", "root", "");
  $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, true);
  }
catch (PDOException $ex) {
  die ("<b>Connection Error!</b><br /><br />{$ex}");
  }
```

My query looks like this.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (user_name, group) VALUES (?, ?)";
```

All data I want to insert into database-table are stored in an array.

```
$data = array();
$data[] = array("User1", "Group1");
$data[] = array("User2", "Group2");
$data[] = array("User3", "Group3");
```

At the end, what I'm trying to do is here:

```
$pdo->beginTransaction();

$res = $pdo->prepare($sql);
foreach ($data as $values) {
  try {
    $res->execute($values);
    }
  catch (PDOException $ex) {
    $pdo->rollBack();
    die ("<b>Error while execute data ({$values[0]}, {$values[1]})</b><br /><br />{$ex}");
    }
  }

$pdo->commit();
```

I'm sure that answer is somewhere above in the code but still have no clue where's the problem. Yep, looks like beginners problem and that really drives me crazy the most.

If you need any more info or updates, let me know. Hope I have provided all relevant code samples and information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer.  According to this link, the solution is to encapsulate your field names.
[PHP PDO Syntax error or access violation: 1064 on insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10556941/php-pdo-syntax-error-or-access-violation-1064-on-insert)

In the previous link, "desc" was a reserved keyword.  In your case, "group" is a reserved word.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html

Try this query instead:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `users` (`user_name`, `group`) VALUES (?, ?)";
```

Comment: Oh God. Never thought about using backticks because of I actually never found usage case where they're needed, all worked well without them before. But actually problem was reserved word **GROUP** and it also works well if I change column-name to **'user_group'** (backticks aren't needed than). Thanks a lot, you saved my day trying to figure out that obvious syntax mistake. Well, your first link confirms that but I never realized it was a problem.